# avformat_open_input causes exception on RTP stream open

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, ffmpeg

I'm trying to program a video player of the RTP stream. I'm using visual studio 2010. When avformat_open_input command is executed an exception is generated (ntdll.dll!774b70f4()). It works fine with normal file from disk(test.avi).

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>

//zeranoe headers and libraries(DLLs also from zeranoe)
extern "C"
{
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
}

#pragma comment(lib, "avcodec.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "avformat.lib")

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx=NULL;
    //char* Filename="c:\\test.avi"; //if I use this there is no crash
    char* Filename="rtp://239.255.42.42:5004";//if I use rtp I receive exception
    int videoStream,i;
    AVCodec         *pCodec=NULL;
    AVCodecContext  *pCodecCtx=NULL;

    avcodec_register_all(); 
    av_register_all();
    avformat_network_init();

    unsigned int _expTime = 5000;
    static const AVIOInterruptCB int_cb = {interrupt_cb, &_expTime};


    // Open video file
    if(avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, Filename , NULL,NULL)!=0)//ntdll.dll exception when I try to open rtp stream
    return -1; // Couldn't open file
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: When I'm trying to open the URL you specified with VLC, I'm asked for admin rights to allow access, and VLC just shows a default screen. Are you sure, something is accessible there (RTP-stream), and you have rights to access it?

Comment: Also specifying `rtp://@239.255.42.42:5004` as recommended didn't change anything, and media info doesn't show anything about this source.

Comment: The RTP stream is local stream on my network. I'm able to play it with  VLC and even with FFPLAY. I also don't expect an exception when there is no stream at all.

Comment: OK (I've been guessing so), just wanted to check how VLC reacts on my Windows 7 OS ;-) ...

Answer (score -1):

Try this before avformat_open_input

pFormatCtx = avformat_alloc_context();

Comment: [No, that's not necessary!](http://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavf__decoding.html#ga10a404346c646e4ab58f4ed798baca32)

Comment: Oh, you are right... It's in my code but not needed... How about this:  AVInputFormat *inf = av_find_input_format("mpegts"); if(avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, filename.c_str(), inf, NULL)!=0)

Comment: Perhaps, but that requires the stream to be mpegts, which we can't say the stream is for sure. FFmpeg will normally probe the stream to determine the type of the stream, and I'd suggest only specifying a format if that probing fails.

Comment: Jonny, thank you very much for your help. I tried booth your suggestions but without success. I still receive the exception and I'm not able to find out what is the reason. There is anybody who was able to receive a stream over network using visual studio.